# Fix relative paths in HTML served by java servlet (for HTML5 pushstate)

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I'm trying to modify a Jetty server which has a servlet (RootResource.java) it somehow magically picks up and uses:

```
@Singleton
@Path("/")
public class RootResource {
    @Context
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @GET
    @Path("react-client/{path: .*\\..+$}")
    public Response serveReactClientContent(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        // This doesn't work, a resolved relative resource is not relative
        // to the /react-client base. See description of problem.
        final String pathToResource = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
        return serveStaticContent(pathToResource);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("react-client/{path: .*$}")
    public Response serveReactClientIndexPage(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return serveStaticContent("/react-client/index.html");
    }

    private Response serveStaticContent(String pathToResource) {
        final String type = this.servletContext.getMimeType(pathToResource);
        final Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(servletContext.getResourceAsStream(pathToResource)).type(type);
        return response.build();
    }
}
```

The idea is to take a GET request to `react-client/some/path` and return the contents of `react-client/index.html`. Essentially making Jetty behave like a webapp server which uses client side routing.

The issue I'm having is that the relative paths in the `index.html` **only work if the path is one level deep** e.g. `react-client/products`.

```
<script src="./webapp.js"></script>
```

In that case the javascript file above in index.html is found because `webapp.js` is a file which exists at `react-client/webapp.js`.

As soon as I try a deeper link e.g. `react-client/products/97357361` that fails as the servlet tries to find `webapp.js` in `react-client/products/webapp.js` which doesn't exist.

How can I make it request the resource always as if it's from `/react-client`? Thanks

Comment: Are you allowing Jetty to serve the static resource (fast, effective, async I/O based, highly configurable)? or are you serving the static resource via your Rest API (slow, memory hog, blocking network send, high thread utilization, inflexible)?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt being a Java noob I wish I knew! Here's the Server.java code if that indicates anything? https://pastebin.com/z5Jv4s93

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Actually there is a web-app/ folder and it serves anything in there so I guess the former.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in Jetty's `DefaultServlet.doGet()`, see if it's being hit.  That will tell you.

Comment: It actually doesn't have any refs to DefaultServlet, I can only guess that using WebAppContext somehow picks a default servlet magically... Java eh ;)

Comment: depends on your `WebAppContext` and its configured `defaultsDescriptor` and `overridesDescriptor` setting.

Comment: It doesn't have those set so is picking it up at the default location - WEB-INF/web.xml. In there is looks like Jersey and then BeanConfig in the bootstrap servlet are used to somehow pick up the directory of web/filter, web/services, web/request etc

Comment: So this is what the default servlet looks like: https://pastebin.com/449Y5MUq

Comment: That DefaultServlet would produce no responses, it has no method overridden for servicing an incoming http method.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I wrote a custom rewrite handler, but even at the point of the `handle` override the relative path has already been incorrectly resolved to the wrong absolute path :(

Comment: Basically this one which I see you commented on: http://jetty.4.x6.nabble.com/Embedded-Jetty-and-Angular-6-only-rewrite-URLs-that-don-t-match-any-servlet-or-files-td4967579.html#a4967586

Comment: If there was just one property somewhere which had the original relative path this would be quite trivial to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `index.html` could get access by multiple urls such as

- /react-client/products
- /react-client/products/97357361
- /react-client/some
- /react-client/some/path

It might be wise to add a `<base>` tag at the header of your HTML page.

```html
<head>
    ...
    <base href="https://www.yourwebsite.com/react-content/" />
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

This will tell the browser to resolve any relative path found in the page as relative to the `https://www.yourwebsite.com/react-content/`

So, according to the example above, `<script src="./script.js"></script>` would be requested to the server as `"https://www.yourwebsite.com/react-content/script.js"` regardless of the current url being use to access this page.

Then, you can revert back those settings on Jetty and keep it simple.

Comment: All these years I never knew about `<base>`, looks like it's working thanks! :o

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things such as filters and [rewrite handlers](http://jetty.4.x6.nabble.com/Embedded-Jetty-and-Angular-6-only-rewrite-URLs-that-don-t-match-any-servlet-or-files-td4967579.html#a4967586) but at no point did Jetty ever provide the original unresolved relative import (e.g. `./webapp`) so I never had an opportunity of rewriting relative resources.

In the end I had to just detect them with a hack in the knowledge that they were nearly all requested from a `/static/` sub directory (I had to add a hard coded exception for `favicon.ico` and `manifest.json`.

```
@GET
@Path("react-client/{path: .*\\..+$}")
public Response serveReactClientContent(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    final String pathToResource = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/react-client/(.+?(?=static/|favicon.ico))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(pathToResource);
    String resolveResourcePath = m.replaceAll("/react-client/");
    return serveStaticContent(resolveResourcePath);
}
```

Not happy with it but it works.